# Best way to control access to a string object in multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, mutex, atomic

I've got a "config" class that has a bunch of attributes that "mirror" configuration settings. A single instance of the class is shared throughout the code (using boost shared_ptr objects) and its attributes read by multiple threads (around 100).

Occasionally, the settings may change and a "monitor" thread updates the appropriate attributes in the object.

For integer and bool attributes, I'm using boost atomic so that when an update happens and the monitor thread sets the value, none of the read threads read it in a partially updated state.

However, for string attributes, I'm worried that making them atomic would hurt performance significantly. It seems like a good way to do it would be to have the string attributes actually be pointers to strings, and then when an update happens, a new string object could be built, and then the write to the shared object (the string pointer) would only be writing the address of the new string object to point to. So I assume that write time would be far shorter than writing a whole new string value to a shared string object.

Doing that, however, means I think I'd want to use shared_ptrs for the string attribs, so that a string object holding the previous value is automatically deleted once all read threads are using the updated string pointer attribute.

So to give an example:

```
class Config
{
  public:
    boost::atomic<boost::shared_ptr<std::string> > configStr1;

    void updateValueInMonitorThread(std::string newValue)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<string> newValuePtr;
        newValuePtr = newValue;
        configStr1 = newValuePtr;
    }
};

void threadThatReadsConfig(boost::shared_ptr<Config> theConfig)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> thingImWorkingOn;
    thingImWorkingOn[*(theConfig->configStr1.load())] = "some value";
}
```

Is that overkill? Is there a better way to do it? I really don't like the way the reading threads have to access the value by dereferencing it and calling .load(). Also, is it even threadsafe, or does that stuff actually negate the safety features of the atomic and/or shared_ptr type?

I know I could use a mutex and read lock it when accessed in a "getter" and write lock it when the monitor thread updates the string's value, but I'd like to avoid that as I'm trying to keep the config class simple and it's going to have dozens, possibly hundreds of these string attributes.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/info!

Answer (score 1):

You are already giving each consumer a shared_ptr to the configuration object. So the threads won't notice if the configuration object isn't always the same object.

That is, when the main configuration changes, generate an entirely new configuration object. That seems like a lot of copying, but I'll bet it happens sufficiently rarely that you won't notice the overhead. Then you can swap the new configuration object in for the old one, and when all the consumers of the old object finish with it, it will disappear.

Obviously, this changes the semantics of the use of a configuration object. A long-running thread which would like to be able to notice configuration changes will have to periodically refresh its configuration object. The easiest way to do that would be just to acquire a new configuration object on every use of configuration data; again, that's unlikely to be too expensive, unless you use a configuration string in a hard loop.

On the plus side, you can make the entire configuration object `const`, which might allow for some optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The classical method of using mutex variables to set a lock on shared resources (here your string objects) is not only the best but the most efficient way of handling such situations, otherwise you may get into trouble because of incomplete protection or you may end-up with a solution that has more overhead.  In some applications you may improve efficiency by using separate mutex locks for separate objects so that if an object is updating, others remain accessible.